# iterating through the key value pairs of a registry hive

Tags: powershell, registry

This:

```
PS C:\Users\mrubinstein> C:\pscode\Untitled31.ps1
@{newproperty=anewvalue; aPrivKey=Adobe.PPKLite; PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security\cHandlers\; PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security; PSChildName=cHandlers; PSDrive=HKCU; PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
@{newproperty=anewvalue; aPrivKey=Adobe.PPKLite; PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security\cHandlers\; PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security; PSChildName=cHandlers; PSDrive=HKCU; PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
```

is the output of that:

```
$arrstring = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security\cHandlers\'
```

Is there any way to get an array back instead of having to make your own array using `String.Split()` (and then another inner array after that)?

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear to me what your desired result is. Do you want an actual array?

```
anewvalue
Adobe.PPKLite
anewvalue
Adobe.PPKLite
```

Then you need something like this:

```
$regpath      = 'HKCU:\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security\cHandlers'
$defaultProps = 'PSChildName','PSDrive','PSParentPath','PSPath','PSProvider'

Get-ItemProperty $regpath |
  ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties } |
  Where-Object { $defaultProps -notcontains $_.Name  } |
  Select-Object -expand value
```

Or do you want a list of custom objects that you can export for instance to a CSV?

```
newproperty   aPrivKey
-----------   --------
anewvalue     Adobe.PPKLite
anewvalue     Adobe.PPKLite
```

Then you need something like this:

```
$regpath      = 'HKCU:\Software\adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\security\cHandlers'
$defaultProps = 'PSChildName','PSDrive','PSParentPath','PSPath','PSProvider'

Get-ItemProperty $regpath | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude $defaultProps
```

Either way you need to remove the default properties from the data you want to extract.